# left position for Bootstrap v2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to get my popover to display to the left of the icon rather than the right, how do I fix this?

```
<i class="icon-info-sign" rel="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-original-title="Title" data-placement="left" data-content="content goes here"></i>
```

Comment: You should be able to shift a popover to the left with the "left" class.  I don't see anything with a popover class, is it included?  The docs for popover may be useful, they are here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers

Comment: Well the popover works in terms of content and display, except I can't get it to display on the left hand side of the icon. The click always returns `<div class="popover fade right in" style="top: -10.5px; left: 1046px; display: block;">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to register this script:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript("", "$('.ipopover').popover();", CClientScript::POS_READY) ?>
```